# Exporting shapefile to KML with set line width using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, kml

I am currently using QGIS 2.18. I have some code to export certain shapefile layers  to bring into KML. When I bring them into Google Earth, the lines are much thinner than I would prefer them to be, and I go through each layer to change their thickness. If possible, I would like to export the KMLs with a certain thickness to  save time. I am using symbologyExport=QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology, and this keeps the color of the layer but the thickness is not maintained.

```
for layer in layers:
name=layer.name()
if "Feeder" in name:
    output_layer = r"(FolderStructureLocation...)" +  name + ".kml"
    QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, output_layer, "utf-8", layer.crs(), "KML",symbologyExport=QgsVectorFileWriter.FeatureSymbology)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using up-to-date GDAL/OGR drivers which uses the `LIBKML` driver for writing kml, you can use the `OGR_STYLE` functionality described at [How to style KML through LIBKML layer creation options?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297494/how-to-style-kml-through-libkml-layer-creation-options/314106) to control line width, color, and various other styling features.

However, since you say you're using a pretty old version of QGIS (2.18 vs the current LTR of 3.4, never mind newest version 3.10), there's at least a chance your installation may also have old OGR drivers not compiled against `LIBKML`, which is required for this to work.