# Exporting to KML file with specifying some symbology (icon styles)

Tags: pyqgis, kml

I created a plugin which allows to export layers from QGIS to KML files, and I want to specify the type of icon of the points in Google Earth.

Some one can tell me if there is a way to do that with `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat`?

For example to make this [icon](http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/purple-stars.png) for my point in my layer.

This is my code

```
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('bpe')[0]
output_layer = r"C:\Users\nassim.mokhtari\Desktop\X.0140253.0.xx_FREE_TCA-SITE-CAB14\03- Livrables\03- Shapes\bpe_test_iface.kml"
name = "Name"
datasource_options = []
datasource_options += ["DescriptionField= "+ name]
datasource_options += ["NameField=" + name]
QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layerRoot, output_layer, "utf-8",layerRoot.crs(), "KML",datasourceOptions=datasource_options)
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat` will invoke OGR to output the layer. If writing to KML *and* your build of GDAL/OGR has the `LIBKML` driver installed, then you can use the [OGR feature style specification](https://gdal.org/user/ogr_feature_style.html) to have limited control over symbols, as well as colours.

In order to do this, you will have to create an additional field, `OGR_STYLE` to provide the instructions for each feature. See [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297494/styling-kml-through-libkml-layer-creation-options) for how to do this for line colours; for symbols you'll have to use a `SYMBOL(...)` tag instead as documented in the first link above.

Note the `SYMBOL(...)` tag documentation refers to predefined OGR symbol IDs, and cursorily describes using system-specific symbols with a `.bmp` file as an example. If you're dead-set on using a range of Google symbols, you'll have to explore whether you can pass a URL to a `.png` instead of a local `.bmp` file. Alternatively, you could use one of the predefined OGR symbol IDs and then post-process the `.kml` file to replace that with the symbol you want.

However, the specific icon you have pointed to seems to be the default Google Earth point icon, just in purple. So you could also try just using `SYMBOL` with a `c:` or `o:` tag and specifying the colour you want. (I haven't tried this).