# Why can't QGIS 3.16 & KML Tools export point symbology for KML/KMZ

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, kml, google-earth

I am trying to export styled points from QGIS to KML/KMZ format. The points are styled according to an attribute value ("Subsidence"). I want to export the KML/KMZ with the symbology, but when I open the result in Google Earth, it isn't preserved. Can someone help me understand why and if there is a way to accomplish this?

[image: QGIS]

[image: Symbology]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Export each class separately, then merge in GE.

Comment: Each class as in each symbol colour? There over 100, is there an option for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this by splitting the vector layer into multiple vector layers based on the value I used to style the points. Then, I gave each file a single point style based on the value. After doing this I ended up with many vector files (one for each value) which I then merged in Google Earth Pro.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS styling is not directly exported in KML. You can, however, construct a style string in a special attribute called `OGR_STYLE` for each feature, and that will be interpreted if you export with the `libkml` driver. More details at [Styling KML through LIBKML layer creation options](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297494/styling-kml-through-libkml-layer-creation-options/314106)

Answer (score 1):

Styling is QGIS-specific and thus you can't just export it and see it in the same shape, color, size etc. in any other application (or only if it has a rendering that matches the one that is implemented in QGIS). Style is not standardized, but program-specific. The yellow markers of Goolge Earth will not be shown the same way in QGIS either (if you do the export the other way round).